# Cannot add and remove class to html elements using Jquery

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/ProductAndServices">
        ProductAndServices
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/EligibilityCriteria">
        EligibilityCriteria
        </a>
    </li>                            
</ul>
```

Changing `<li>` element's class to 'active' by following code:

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').on('click', function () {
    $('.navbar-nav li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

is giving no error inside console, but not giving desired output.

Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your HTML preferably as a [mcve]

Comment: What do you get when you console log `$(this)`?

Comment: [cannot reproduce it](https://jsfiddle.net/xdq1hnm4/). Please provide the code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: If you are navigating via href how would your on click work? It navigates or reloads

Comment: @trincot: I've changed the topic and description.

Comment: you are moving to a different page before active class shows up. Maybe you need to set active in your target page depending on your target page HTML...

Comment: When you navigate away from the page by clicking on the link, you will lose the active class.  A new page will be loaded, with the default state. The web is stateless by default.

Comment: @SurajRao, but while debugging in the browser and clicking on the `<a>` is giving me onclick event.

Comment: Button != anchor tag with target link. `<a>` tag loads the href

Comment: @SurajRao, This is on the shared layout file.

Comment: @JonP, but this code is on shared layout file.

Comment: It makes no difference, when a new page is loaded in the browser, it is a brand new page, regardless of shared layout. New URL , new page.

Comment: @JonP Yes. I figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```js
$(this).parent.addClass('active');
```

I believe you're trying to refer to the parent *element* which is not a function. Maybe that's why the code doesn't work!

Comment: jQuery does support `.parent()`. At least I used to remember that, it's been so long now since I last used it

Comment: It still exists [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: this is not working